# Keep ubuntu server running when computer shut down

Tags: 18.04, raspberrypi

Now I've installed ubuntu server on my **raspberry pi**, so it's still running as I want. thanks

Comment: A server can't run when it's off.

Comment: what is turned off? `computer` or `virtualbox` or `ubuntu `

Comment: A server cannot be running when a computer is off.  Web sites, etc. that serve requests from users do this by having the computer remain on 24 hours a day, 365 days a year.

Comment: If you need a server running 24/7 but don't have dedicated hardware, you'll have to look into a cloud server solution - which will cost you some $$ per month. There are many providers of this kind of service.

Comment: @Ray thanks, the information is very helpful

Comment: @ArturMeinild I already know a little about that, I have a vps like that, but now I'm learning to make my own local server for the purpose of learning more about the Linux system.

Comment: Indeed, a cloud service would "solve" your problem but nothing you're hoping for can answer your question as it is currently posed above.  When a computer is "off", it is "off" and it cannot do anything.  A cloud service just means that someone else's computer is "on" 24/7.  It doesn't answer your question -- perhaps you should rephrase your question?

Comment: @Ray I have to quote this

"sorry I'm newbie to such things with my limited knowledge, how do I keep this server running when my computer is shut down?

what problem is there a solution? I would really appreciate your comments, thank you"

outline of a solution, if there is a solution it will be better, if there is no solution let it be experience.

Why do I have to repeat my question? leave it like this so that later people have the same problem as me, he can read the comments on this question. any suggestions that are more logical and mature?

Comment: If you do not want to repeat your question, that's your choice.  It is not for later people, but for YOU so that you can get answers that are more suited to what you want.  The way you phrased your question is impossible to satisfy.  A computer that is off cannot do anything.  Newbie or not, you need to understand this first.  If you want to use a cloud service, then your question should be phrased in a way so that you want your own computer "off", but you want someone else's computer "on".That's ok and someone will lead you down the "cloud service" path with details.

Comment: @Ray you make too complicated your opinion
relax

Comment: Just trying to help you...  If you don't appreciate it then surely I won't waste my time further.  Good luck to you!

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu server in VirtualBox runs on your computer. When you switch off your computer, VirtualBox and anything inside go down as well, together with everything else on your computer.
Also if you stop VirtualBox, everything in it (in this case Ubuntu Server) go down.
What you are trying to do is not possible.

Comment: **Nothing is impossible** in my dictionary, but thank you for giving my comment, I appreciate it for your time.

Comment: hijaben, you changed your comment, you originally stated there was some script on internet which could do it. It cannot. And you also changed your original post, so now somebody who did not see it before has no idea what all people here spent their time on helping you.

Comment: And yes, running something on a computer which is switched off **is impossible** at a current state of technology.